# Upgrading from .NET 3.5 to 4. Questions to think about?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Curious about things to consider to avoid any code breaks, etc to upgrade from .NET 3.5 to 4.

I am particularly interested in:
- What would be the server requirements to deploy a .NET 4 app? Does it need any particular version of IIS and Windows Server to run?

I am facing serious performance issues with Entity Framework due to the large size of database and initialization takes long time for the first user to login. .NET 4 seems to realize this as a widespread issue and has something called PreWarm apps. Scottgu's post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) seems to talk more about it. But, curious if this will work on IIS 6 and WinServer 2003.

Are there any other things i need to think of before making the switch to .NET 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Framework 4 Beta 2 can be installed on Windows Server 2003. The [software requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DED875C8-FE5E-4CC9-B973-2171B61FE982&displaylang=en) are:

> **Supported Operating Systems:** Windows
>   Server 2003; Windows Server 2008;
>   Windows Vista; Windows XP
>
> .NET Framework 4 can be installed on the
>   following operating systems:
>   - Windows XP SP3
>   - Windows Server 2003 SP2
>   - Windows Vista SP1
>   - Windows 7
>   - Windows Server 2008 (not supported on Server Core Role)
>    - Windows Server 2008 R2 (not supported on Server Core Role)
>   Note that .NET Framework 4 is currently in Beta. If you have a working app on production, you might want to consider waiting for its RTM.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks dude. How about support for IIS6? My current production environment is IIS6 and Win2003. I am trying to understand, if i can take full potential of .NET 4 on my current environment or will it require upgrade IIS7.

Comment: Well, you can use almost everything in .NET 4 in IIS6 too. Of course, you cannot use newer IIS7 features that take advantage of .NET like Integrated mode. For the most part, it's OK.